# How do I reliably determine file type when FileMagic is not an option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, ruby-on-rails-5, mime-types, file-type

I'm using Rails 5.0.3.  How do I reliably determine file type (this is from a file on my computer, not one I just downloaded from the Internet) without relying on file extensions?  I would like a cross-platform way to do this only because I'm using Mac for development and Linux for test/prod.  Also, the gem file magic is not an option because of this error

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.1)

    filemagic was resolved to 0.3.5.0, which depends on
      rails (< 5, >= 4.2.0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`filemagic`](https://rubygems.org/gems/filemagic) isn't the gem you're looking for. This appears to be someone's project not intended for public consumption (the rubygems page links to a company's website, and no source code is available).

Instead, install the [`ruby-filemagic`](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-filemagic/versions/0.7.1) gem. Here's the [source](https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic) and [documentation](http://blackwinter.github.io/ruby-filemagic/). We can use the library like so:

```
begin
  fm = FileMagic.new(FileMagic::MAGIC_MIME)
  puts fm.file("foo.txt", true)
ensure
  fm.close
end
```

...or by using the `open()` helper method, which automatically closes the resource for us:

```
FileMagic.open(FileMagic::MAGIC_MIME) { |fm| puts fm.file("foo.txt", true) }
```

This also works with yet another helper, `mime()`, which additionally sets the flag for us:

```
FileMagic.mime { |fm| puts fm.file("foo.txt", true) }
```

This gem relies on [*libmagic*](https://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic), a library used to identify file types using the file's [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number). The [*file*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command, commonly found on Unix/Linux systems, uses the same library:

```
$ file --mime-type foo.txt
foo.txt: text/plain
```

We can also invoke this command from the Ruby application to get a file's MIME type:

```
IO.popen(["file", "--mime-type", "--brief", "foo.txt"]) { |io| puts io.read.chomp }
```

[MimeMagic](https://github.com/minad/mimemagic) is an alternative to FileMagic.

Comment: How do I invoke the FileMgaic functionality from Ruby?  Using the docs --https://blackwinter.github.io/ruby-filemagic/, I tried "FileMagic.file('/tmp/myfile')" but got an error "NoMethodError: undefined method `file' for FileMagic:Clas"

Comment: @Dave, we need to instantiate the class first. I updated the answer with some examples.